# Why is np.size("") 1?

Tags: python, numpy

I wonder if there is a rationale behind the fact that `np.size('')` returns `1`, given the fact that `len('')` or `np.size([])`, for instance, both return `0`.

Comment: look at `np.array('')`.  It's shape is `()`.

Comment: Think of it as a scalar, not a container.  `np.size("123")` is also 1.

Comment: That's right, with a scalar it also returns 1, but at least it has more logical sense since it is not empty. What bothers me is that the string is empty, and in many cases it does not differ from an empty list, tuple, or array...

Comment: `np.array` is setup, primarily, to make arrays from lists, and list like iterables (e.g. tuple), and provided the 'nesting' isn't ragged, the `len` corresponds to the 1st dimension of the array.  But it does not treat a string as an iterable.  `np.array('foobar')`, has shape `()`, with a big enough `U` dtype.  It treats `np.array('')` in similar manner.  `np.array(['a','','abc'])` is a 3 element array; the empty string is just another string.

Comment: You'll see in SO, the `shape` is used much more often than `size`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`np.size` of any `str` is 1. This is also true of most Python objects which are not lists.

Calling `help` on it prints:

```
Help on function size in module numpy:

size(a, axis=None)
    Return the number of elements along a given axis.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    a : array_like
        Input data.
    axis : int, optional
        Axis along which the elements are counted.  By default, give
        the total number of elements.
    
    Returns
    -------
    element_count : int
        Number of elements along the specified axis.
...
```

From this we see that the provided first argument ought to be "array_like", and so should not be a `str` in any case.

The source code of the body of `np.size` is:

```
if axis is None:
    try:
        return a.size
    except AttributeError:
        return asarray(a).size
else:
    try:
        return a.shape[axis]
    except AttributeError:
        return asarray(a).shape[axis]
```

When provided a `str`, it calls `asarray` on the object. This results in a 0-dimensional array being created, which will always have a size of 1.

```
>>> a = np.asarray('')
>>> a
array('', dtype='<U1')
>>> a.size
1
>>> a.ndim
0
>>> 
>>> b = np.asarray('example str')
>>> b
array('example str', dtype='<U11')
>>> b.size
1
>>> b.ndim
0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Will for your ellaborate answer. Indeed it behaves this way because it has been programmed (and documented) this way. But I still wonder if it would bring any benefit an alternative implementation returning 0 for this particular case

Comment: You're right that it is somewhat odd behaviour. I presume they expect people won't pass non-array-like objects into the method in normal use. Implementing it as they have puts the burden of ensuring the object is array-like on the user, which helps make their API work for more use-cases. If they raised an exception for objects which aren't array-like, then they'd have to detect what "array-like" even means, which might mean raises exceptions when they shouldn't. Feel free to open an issue on their issue tracker to discuss what the behaviour here should be: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues